# Merging legend of 2 graphical layers in ggplot2 and ggstar with geom_point and geom_star

Tags: r, ggplot2

I spent a whole day trying to fix this silly graphical issue without success...

I have a pcoa dataset with 10 population let say "special" (I want to display them as solid symbols) and 4 "non special" (4 non solid symbols).

I want one legend with each symbol related to a species and each color to a population of both the "special" and "non special" population.

an example

```
df <- data.frame(Species=sort(rep(letters[1:10], 14)), Locality=sort(rep(LETTERS[1:10], 14)), Axis.1=rnorm(140,0,0.7), Axis.2=rnorm(140,0,0.7))

#NOTE:in the original dataset, 2 population may share the same species, thus the same symbol

special<- ("A","B","C","D",E","F","G","H","I","J") #this must be solid symbol
non_special<-("K","M","N","O") # this must be empty symbols

df.special<–subset(df, Species== special)
df.non.special<–subset(df, Species == non_special)

library(ggplot)
library(ggstar)


#solid symbols for special population
ggplot(data= df.special, aes(x=Axis.1,y=Axis.2, fill= Locality)) + 
      geom_star(aes(starshape=Species), size=2)+
scale_starshape_manual(values=c(1,5,9,15,14,13,11,23,21,28))+

#empty symbols for non special population
geom_point(data= df.non.special, aes(x = Axis.1,  y = Axis.2, shape=Species, color=Locality), size=2)+
scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend", values=c(8,11,13,14))+

#additional style
theme_bw()+ xlab("Axis.1=30%") + 
 ylab("Axis.2=20%")+ 
theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black"), 
 axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

The desired output should be a scatterplot with one legend with both solid and empty symbols for special and non special population, respectively,  colored as different Species.

Thus I need to implement somehow
scale_fill_manual and scale_shape_manual (empty symbols needed) and adding scale_fill_manual to scale_starshape_manual.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to

1. use the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to set the `shape`s/`starshape`s for the `color`/`fill` legends.
2. Get rid of the `shape` and `starshape` legend
3. Get rid of the legend title for the color legend which in my case is the second or bottom legend.
4. Remove the `spacing` and the `margin` for the legends so that they appear as one.

Note: I slightly adjusted your example data and code as it was not working and e.g. did not include any non special characters. See below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstar)

ggplot(data = df.special, aes(x = Axis.1, y = Axis.2)) +
  geom_star(aes(starshape = Species, fill = Locality), size = 2) +
  scale_starshape_manual(values = c(1, 5, 9, 15, 14, 13, 11, 23, 21, 28)) +
  geom_point(data = df.non.special, aes(shape = Species, color = Locality), size = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8, 11, 13, 14)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Axis.1=30%") +
  ylab("Axis.2=20%") +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      override.aes = list(shape = c(8, 11, 13, 14)),
      order = 2
    ),
    shape = "none",
    fill = guide_legend(
      override.aes = list(starshape = c(1, 5, 9, 15, 14, 13, 11, 23, 21, 28)),
      order = 1
    ),
    starshape = "none"
  ) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"), legend.margin = margin())
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
  Species = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:14], 10)),
  Locality = sort(rep(letters[1:14], 10)),
  Axis.1 = rnorm(140, 0, 0.7),
  Axis.2 = rnorm(140, 0, 0.7)
)

special <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
non_special <- c("K", "L", "M", "N")

df.special <- subset(df, Species %in% special)
df.non.special <- subset(df, Species %in% non_special)
```

Comment: HI! thank you! It worked perfectly! I couldn't get through it without your help!